# Как работает компонент Console в Symfony 3?

Tags: php, консоль, symfony

Пример класса некой команды:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

class NewCommand extends Command
{

    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
          ->setName('new-command')
          ->setDescription('Creates a new user.')
          ->setHelp('This command allows you to create a user...');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $output->writeln('New command');
    }

}
```

Как Symfony находит этот класс и регистрирует его как консольную команду?
Ведь при автолоадинге невозможно определить какие классы наследуются от базового (в данном случае, класса Command).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Симфони регистрирует команды двумя способами:

- Регистрирует все команды из всех зарегистрированных бандлов, которые находятся в директории Command (в какой-то версии symfony удалил эту возможность, уже не помню в какой, в 4-ой этого уже наверное нет)
- Ручная регистрация команд через контейнер, то есть создаете сервис и добавляете тэг с названием console.command

Answer (score 0):

Что бы оно работало, надо зарегистрировать команду в bin/console смотри документацию https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/components/console.html

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php
// application.php

require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;

$application = new Application();

// ... register commands
$application->add(new \AppBundle\Command\NewCommand());

$application->run();
```

Вот так оно его и находит

Comment: Да, но это если использовать этот компонент независимо от фреймворка Symfony.
При использование с фреймворком, достаточно добавить класс команды, чтобы команда стала доступной в консоли.